# Search based on many to many relation with multiple condition on same column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a **many to many relation** on my **laravel 5.3** project.
There is two models associated with this problem. They are **Job** and **Tag**.
The model **Job** can have many **Tag** associated with it and also the model **Tag** related to many **Job**.
I have assigned the relation **Many To Many** using the key word "**belongsToMany**" in both model classes.
The database of the relation is :
table: *jobs*

```
________________
 id |  title    |
____|___________|
  1 |  Developer|
____|___________|
  2 |  Designer |
____|___________|
  3 |  Tester   |
____|___________|
  4 |  manager  |
____|___________|
```

table : *tags*

```
_________________
 id |  tag_name |
____|___________|
  1 |  php      |
____|___________|
  2 |  html     |
____|___________|
  3 |  css      |
____|___________|
```

and the **pivot table** : *job_tag*

```
_____________________
 job_id |  tag_id   |
________|___________|
  1     |   1       |
________|___________|
  1     |   2       |
________|___________|
  2     |   1       |
________|___________|
  3     |   1       |
________|___________|
  3     |   2       |
________|___________|
  4     |   2       |
________|___________|
```

The user can pass multiple tag names to retrieve the jobs which are related to the both tags which are passed by the user.(**AND** condition)

Example: when a user passes the **tag_name** "php" and "html" i want to display the details of the jobs [id:1 title:developer] and [id:2 title:designer].

**Hint** : *retrieve the job records which have the tags both "php" and "html"*

NB: the number of the tag names passed by the user is not defined ie, user can pass as much as they can.

---

Here is something i have tried:

```
$jobs = Job::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use($params) {
                    foreach ($params['tags'] as $tag) {
                        $query->where('tag', $tag);
                    }
                });
```

The above code doesnt returns anything but generates the following sql:

```
select * from `jobs` where exists (select * from `tags` inner join `job_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `job_tag`.`tag_id` where `job_tag`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` and (`tag` = css) and (`tag` = javascript))
```

I was tried to get results based on this sql, which doesn't work.

Hope you people understand my problem and will help me find a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use multiple `whereHas` as:

```
$query = Job::query();

foreach ($params['tags'] as $tag) {
    $query->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use($tag) {
        $q->where('tag', $tag);
    });
}

$jobs = $query->get();
```

OR

Assuming you have an array of tag `id` as:

```
$tag_ids = [2, 4];
```

Then you can try as:

```
Job::whereHas('tags', function($q) use($tag_ids) {
        $q->whereIn('tag_id', $tag_ids)
          ->groupBy('job_id')
          ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = '.count($tag_ids));
    })->get();
```

Comment: The first option works well. it generates a query like this :- `select * from 'jobs' where exists (select * from 'tags' inner join 'job_tag' on 'tags'.'id' = 'job_tag'.'tag_id' where 'job_tag'.'job_id' = 'jobs'.'id' and 'tag' = "php") and exists (select * from 'tags' inner join 'job_tag' on 'tags'.'id' = 'job_tag'.'tag_id' where 'job_tag'.'job_id' = 'jobs'.'id' and 'tag' = "html")`._Thank You_

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach, you need the tags to be compared with `OR` instead of `AND`.

```
$jobs = Job::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($params) {
    $query->where(function ($query2) use ($params) {
        foreach ($params['tags'] as $tag) {
            $query->orWhere('tag', $tag);
        }
    })
});
```

I'm not sure if the second level of closure is necessary, but it will help if you end up adding on any other `WHERE` conditions to your query after the fact.

Comment: The code generates an error: `unexpected '}'` and if the `$query->where(function ($query2) use ($params) {` is removed then all 'jobs' are listed instead of the tag related search.